# Applying a function that returns error message: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return a function that would return 'OPTY_CLOSE_DATE' from the next cell down as the 'END_DATE' only when the 'REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG' goes from 1 to 0. A certain condition of the next row being the same 'SCU_KEY' and 'PRODUCT' must be met. So if you see row 2 (index #334), I want for the first row (index #45) to have an 'END_DATE' as the 'OPTY_CLOSE_DATE' from the second row. So instead of the '2020-04-15' you see as the first row's 'END_DATE' (index #45), I want the value to be '2019-12-09' that you see on next rows 'OPTY_CLOSE_DATE'.

Image of dataframe is shown and also the code I tried that ended with an error message of: 'Timestamp' obect is not subscriptable.

```
def time1to0(df):
    if (df['SCU_KEY'] == df['SCU_KEY'].shift(1)) and (df['PRODUCT'] == df['PRODUCT'].shift(1)) and (df['REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'].shift(1) == 0):
        return df['OPTY_CLOSE_DATE'].shift(1)

df_5['END_DATE'].apply(time1to0)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're supplying the correct type to your function. You appear to be supplying a `pd.Series` where your function appears to be expecting a `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: Ohh ok, yeah I should have remembered that principle. Do you know the best way of fixing the issue or to address a solution differently?

Comment: Can the function just be applied on `df_5`? What does the `END_DATE` column have to do with this?

Comment: If you're trying to assign what's in the `return` statement to the `END_DATE` column, do that within the function.